# Generalised Pareto Distribution MLE R code

Tags: r, statistics

I've written a function to calculate the MLE estimates of a Generalised Pareto Distribution.  When I use it with any data though I'm getting errors like this

```
1: In log(beta * ksi) : NaNs produced
2: In nlm(loglik, theta, stepmax = 5000, iterlim = 1000) :
  NA/Inf replaced by maximum positive value
```

I was wondering if anyone could spot any mistakes with my code?

```
MLGPD<-function(data){
    xi0 <- 1
    beta0 <- 360
    theta <- c(xi0, beta0)
    excess <- data
    assign("tmp", excess)
    loglik <- function(theta){
        ksi <- theta[1]
        beta <- theta[2]
        y <- ((tmp - 0.1)/beta)
        f <- ((1/ksi)+1)*sum(log(1+y)) + length(tmp) * log(beta*ksi)
        f
    }
    fit <- nlm(loglik, theta, stepmax = 5000, iterlim= 1000)
    return(fit)
    par.ests <- fit$x
    return(par.ests)
}

#Checking our MLE algorithm works:

rgpd<-function(n,ksi, beta){
    10000+beta*(((1-runif(n, min=0, max=1))^-ksi)-1)
}

rgpd1 <- rgpd(100, 1, 2.5)

MLGPD(rgpd1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Umm, first thing that jumps out at me as soon as I look at it -- how do you get to the second return?

Comment: Sorry the last 2 lines weren't supposed to be there.  It shouldn't effect it anyway.

Comment: Have a look at what you're assigning to tmp or excess. e.g. `head(excess)` ... then look at what is in `data` the same way. Check it's all what it should be. Maybe try the debugging tools.